# Separate renderng thread in Android (OpenGL ES 2.0)

Tags: android, opengl-es2, multithreading

I'm used to mainly working with the Canvas SurfaceView API on Android and have recently been learning openGL ES 2.0

With canvas I know that surfaceView gives you the ability to start a new thread to render on, but it doesn't specifically do this for you, so I was creating a new thread and managing that thread when the app was ended / paused etc....

However, from what I've read with glSurfaceView it seems that this is actually done for you automatically? Does this mean I don't actually need to manually create / start and manage my own rendering thread? (I'm talking specifically about a rendering thread (which could also be used for logic updates) which is separate the main UI thread.

Clarification on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

All rendering is done on a separate thread, and this is done for you automatically.
The documentation is very explicit about this (quoted from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer.html) :

> **Threading**
>
> The renderer will be called on a separate thread, so that rendering
>   performance is decoupled from the UI thread. Clients typically need to
>   communicate with the renderer from the UI thread, because that's where
>   input events are received. Clients can communicate using any of the
>   standard Java techniques for cross-thread communication, or they can
>   use the queueEvent(Runnable) convenience method.

This means you do NOT have to create and manage a rendering thread yourself.

I hope this clarifies the matter :)